# Notifications Runtime Permissions Android 13

Tags: android, runtime, android-permissions, android-13

Maybe someone has read about The runtime permission for push notifications in Android 13. I have no problem with this, but I have a question that I can't find in the documentation.

Do you know if **InApp Messages ( fierebase )** also need to ask for this new permission?

I would really appreciate your help. Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

In-app messages are like a dialog and it is a View. So No no need for notification permission.
This permission is just needed to [show](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notification-permission) non-foreground service notifications. For example, showing notification when a new email is received in an email app.